# GmailLabel.getThreads returns an incorrect number of threads

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Has anyone noticed that the `GmailLabel.getThreads(start,max)` evaluates incorrectly in a number of cases, particularly when the `start` index exceeds the number of threads in the label? For example, I have a label with 770 threads. I observed these results:

```
userLabel.getThreads(500,500).length; // Returns 270. Expected 270
userLabel.getThreads(600,500).length; // Returns 70. Expected 170
userLabel.getThreads(700,500).length; // Returns 0. Expected 70
userLabel.getThreads(1000,500).length; // Returns 0. Expected 0
userLabel.getThreads(1001,500).length; // Returns 268. Expected 0
```

Would anyone be able to verify if this is or isn't the expected behaviour?

Comment: I am also seeing similar results. In my instance I should have 1600 results but it only returns 770.